# Configuring the host in server to be accessible to external devices

Tags: android, url, networking, server, c++14

I adopted the code for MJPEG streaming from this repository: https://github.com/JPery/MJPEGWriter

Now, I ran the code successfully on Ubuntu 16.04 and when I ran the client side code on the same machine, I was able to receive the Webcam stream on the client, which was on the same machine (I had to type $ ./clview http://127.0.0.1:7777 to get the stream).

But, when I try to access the server from my phone which is connected to the laptop's hotspot, I don't get any stream, and finally get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. How achieved this was by creating an app that decodes MJPEG stream (using the url that contains the IP address of the server) and displays it in WebView widget of the app.

So I wanted to know if it is a problem with the configuration of the host so that it should be made visible(or accessible) to external devices also (and not just self) or some mistake in entering the url in the app for receiving the MJPEG stream. The url that I was using in the app was http://10.42.0.1:7777.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got to know the error. Problem was not with the host, but with my firewall. I had UFW on my Ubuntu pc, which had been set to **deny incoming** by default. So, I changed it to **allow incoming** and now the stream works perfectly. And yes, there is no necessity to configure the host in any manner, except for allowing a port for it to serve on.

Thanks!